# Is it arrogance to want to be given credit for your work instead of other people?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad, allah, helping

At school, I'm a founder of a club relating to a subject I'm extremely passionate about. My best friend is a co-founder of the club. I worked extremely hard to get this club to start up. My friend didnt really do much. He did like 10% of the job where I did 90%.

The thing is, my friend being the head of 3 other clubs gets most of the credit and most of the recognition whereas people barely approach me with anything related to it. I want more credit because I created the whole thing.

Is it haram in Islam to want to be recognized for your work? I am afraid of falling into arrogance, so is it considered arrogance?

On a related note, is there any place where Allah or his messenger say that people will be given credit for their work in this world?

Comment: I tried to make it more clear and concise. Hopefully, your point is still in the question.

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Please check out a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) of our site to learn more about how this site works.